# Using definition of limit of Sequence show that, If x>0 then limit of Sequence (Arctan nx) is π/2

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, sequence-of-function

> **Question**: I need to show by "using definition of limit of Sequence" that Sequence $(\arctan nx)$ converges to $π/2$ if $x>0$.

My attempt: i need to show for any $\epsilon >0$, and for each $x>0$, we have $|\arctan nx -π/2|<\epsilon$ for sufficiently large $n$. How do i proceed further, unable to solve it. Please help.

Comment: You can use the fact that $|\arctan(nx)-\pi/2|=\pi/2-\arctan(nx).$

Comment: @K.defaoite sir then?

Comment: @K.defaoite sir, let $\epsilon >0$ be given, then by your hint, $|\arctan nx -π/2|=π/2-\arctan nx$ Hence $|\arctan nx -π/2| <\epsilon$ iff $π/2-\arctan nx <\epsilon$ iff $-\arctan nx<\epsilon-π/2$ iff $\arctan nx>π/2-\epsilon$ iff $nx>\tan(π/2-\epsilon)$ iff $n>\tan(π/2-\epsilon)/x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: following up on K.defaoite's reply, consider any integer $$N > \frac{\tan(\pi/2 - \varepsilon)}{x}$$ and use that as the lower bound for sufficiently large $n$.

Edit: I've put a full solution in the spoiler box below.

> Let $\varepsilon > 0$. We wish to show that there exists a sufficiently large integer $N$ for which $\lvert\arctan{nx} - \pi/2\rvert < \varepsilon$ for all $n \geq N$.
>  Define $\varepsilon_0 = \min(\varepsilon, \pi/4)$, and take $N$ to be any integer such that $$N > \frac{\tan(\pi/2 - \varepsilon_0)}{x}.$$ Then for all $n \geq N$, \begin{align*}\lvert\arctan{nx} - \pi/2\rvert &= \pi/2 - \arctan(nx)\\ &\leq \pi/2 - \arctan(Nx) \\ &< \pi/2 - \arctan\bigg(\frac{\tan(\pi/2 - \varepsilon_0)}{x} \cdot x \bigg) \\ &= \pi/2 - (\pi/2 - \varepsilon_0) \\ &\leq \varepsilon, \end{align*} as desired. Note that the first equality holds because $\pi/2 > \arctan{x}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and the inequalities in lines 2 and 3 hold because $\arctan$ is increasing on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Sir, what if $\epsilon =π$ ? We get $tan(-π/2)$ in numerator on right hand side, which is not defined

Comment: In the spirit of epsilon-delta arguments, the point of the first statement "for any $\varepsilon > 0$" is more so a guarantee that the argument works for "all sufficiently small $\varepsilon$." If you really want to be picky about the rigor of the proof, just choose a sufficiently small $\varepsilon_0 < \varepsilon$ to make your argument, or redefine $\varepsilon_0 = \min(\varepsilon, \delta)$ for some sufficiently small $\delta$.

Comment: But, in definition of limit of Sequence say, "for any $\epsilon >0$" so for $\epsilon=π$ too the inequality, $|Arctan(nx)-π/2|<\epsilon$ must holds, for sufficiently large n. But how such a natural number $ n $ exists? $n > \tan(-π/2)/x$

Comment: What I mean is, if for whatever reason someone chooses $\varepsilon = \pi$, you don't have to use $\varepsilon$ in your proof. You can prove the inequality for a value of $\varepsilon$ that is smaller, like $\pi/4$, which implies $\lvert\arctan(nx) - \pi/2\rvert < \pi/4 < \varepsilon$, which is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks you so much for last comment, it gives much more clarity to me. Thanks for the help, sir.

Comment: Further, can you please elaborate how, K.defaoite's reply help us to consider above inequality for $n$?

Comment: Sir, is i get it correctly?  let $\epsilon >0$ be given, then by your hint, $|\arctan nx -π/2|=π/2-\arctan nx$ Hence $|\arctan nx -π/2| <\epsilon$ iff $π/2-\arctan nx <\epsilon$ iff $-\arctan nx<\epsilon-π/2$ iff $\arctan nx>π/2-\epsilon$ iff $nx>\tan(π/2-\epsilon)$ iff $n>\tan(π/2-\epsilon)/x$